# Windows 10 quick access feature still shows “ghost folder” from removed hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

I recently did a clean install of Windows 10 on my PC, along with a brand new solid state `C:` drive.

After the install, I reconnected my old `C:` drive to copy over some of the few files I wanted to keep. The quick access feature decided to list the old “Downloads” folder as frequently used. Now that that drive is removed, the shortcut is still there and I constantly click it, since it’s just labeled “Downloads.”

I need to figure out how to remove it, but it won’t let me delete it since the path doesn’t exist. I threw out the drive, so I can’t just plug it back in and actually delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gross workaround, but it should work. We can fool Windows into thinking the folder is there on the drive by mounting a folder as a drive with the right letter.

Create a temporary folder somewhere, I'll use `C:\temp`. Open an administrative command prompt. If the drive's letter was `F` when it was plugged in, type this:

```
subst F: C:\temp
```

Windows now believes there is a drive with letter `F` in your machine, but in reality it is just pointing at that temporary folder. Create a folder hierarchy matching the location of the ghost folder on that fake drive. You can use Explorer (might have to close and reopen it for it to see the new "drive"), or the command prompt:

```
md F:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads
```

You are now able to remove the ghost entry because there is a folder with that path on your computer. Once it is done, remove the letter substitution:

```
subst F: /D
```

Torch the temporary folder, close the command prompt, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run Command Prompt in elevated mode(Run as Administrator), and run the command "chkdsk C: /r" without the quotes. Replace C: with your drive letter.
This will check the disk for errors, but also for bad file links and other unwantedness....